# Is a PHP session secure?

Tags: php, session, security

Now I don't care about data transmission - no man-in-the-middle, that's work of http and https.

As far as I know PHP identifies sessions with the http cookie. But what happens if anyone tries bruteforce guessing session ids?

Comment: What are you trying to do actually ?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html)...

Comment: I store logged user id in php session. But i don't know if sessions are safe.

Comment: Nothing is 100% secure. With enough will, anything can be cracked, one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its safe to assume that nothing is secure..

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack
- http://www.serversidemagazine.com/php/session-hijacking/

Comment: it's safe to assume that, but if you assume that you get paranoid, and you will end up using tons of scripts just for login.

Comment: Sessions are 100% NOT secure. Paranoid or not, they simply cannot be considered safe for a primary login method. Take a look at http://codebutler.com/firesheep which will hijack sessions on your local network - That is a example of how bad sessions are.

Comment: @Mihail: it's good to be paranoid. And I hope all IT departments that house data about me are paranoid, too. However, I must assume they are not. I must assume nobody is except myself. You guys don't get my data, get off my lawn. You, you and you.

Answer (score 2):

[Andreas Bogk](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Mar/519) made some very reasonable recommendations about a year ago to address a cryptographic weakness in the session key generation logic in PHP versions 5.3.2 and earlier that made PHP sessions more vulnerable to "session hijacking" (which seems to be your primary concern) than they ought to have been.

And [Przemek Sobstel](http://segfaultlabs.com/files/pdf/php-session-security.pdf) wrote a generic catalogue of attack types (including session hijacking) targeting the PHP session mechanism over 4 years ago, along with suggestions for mitigating them. The latest PHP version has changed several times since then, as has the "threat landscape". But the attack types have not changed much since then, and neither have the recommended best practices.

If you want to *quantify* your risk exposure, then you're going to have to define your scenario (implementation, environment, etc.) more precisely.

Comment: +1 for mentioning this. PHP's PRNG has had a rather troubled history. See comment in col shrapnel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> But what happens if anyone tries bruteforce of guessing session ids?

they would be aging...

Comment: Not necessarily true. PHP has had a rather poor history of Insufficient Entropy vulnerabilities ( https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insufficient_entropy_in_pseudo-random_number_generator ) See this search at the security vulnerability database cvedetails http://cvedetails.com/google-search-results.php?cx=partner-pub-9597443157321158%3Advjtec-wfv5&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&q=php+entropy&sa=Search&siteurl=www.cvedetails.com%2Fcve%2FCVE-2008-4102%2F This has then been made even worse by some apps then seeding weakly e.g. Joomla http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2008-4102/